# Process finished with exit code 0 error while using multiple tags in Cucumber version 7.2.3

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

Below is my Runner file:

```
@CucumberOptions(

    plugin = {"json:target/cucumber.json"},

    features = "src/test/resources/features",

    glue = "com/company/definitions",

    dryRun = false,

    tags = "@test1 and @test2" 
)
```

If there is only 1 tag, then it is running correctly; but if I add another tag (i.e.@test1 and @test2), then it is giving "Process finished with exit code 0" error in the console.

I have tried all the possible options even the old versions without any success. Is there an update in Cucumber related to tags? Anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

The [Tag Expression](https://github.com/cucumber/tag-expressions) `@test1 and @test2` selects all scenarios that are tagged with both `@test1` and `@test2`. If you want all scenarios with atleast one of those two tags you should use `@test1 or @test2`.

Comment: 'or' is running all the tags, whereas 'and' is not working at all. Nonetheless it did solve my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you misunderstand the meaning of `and` in this context. Try tagging a scenario with both tags and use `and`.

Comment: if I use 'and' with tags then I have "Process finished with exit code 0" error in the console.