# How to run multiple tags in cucumber Junit

Tags: java, junit, automation, cucumber

I'm trying to run Cucumber project based on Java.
In Pom.xml I'm using :

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>7.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And in the runner class I try to pass two tags

`@RunWith(Cucumber.class) @CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources"}, plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports.html", "json:target/cucumber.json", "junit:target/junit-cucumber-reports/Cucumber-junit.xml", "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"}, glue = {"/"}, tags = "@PW and @WM" )`

I have this output in th console [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfTbE.png)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75209443/process-finished-with-exit-code-0-error-while-using-multiple-tags-in-cucumber-ve

Comment: Thank you for return. This video explain the concept in using tags : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdwjendx-mc&ab_channel=AutomationStepbyStep

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. in this question

If you have one feature that contain @tag1 and another one that contain @tag2
to run both of them use tags="@tag1 or @tag2"

But if we use tags="@tag1 and @tag2" that mean that one feature contains two tags named @tag1 @tag2 else nothing will be run that's the same error happen to me

[Process finished with exit code 0 error while using multiple tags in Cucumber version 7.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75209443/process-finished-with-exit-code-0-error-while-using-multiple-tags-in-cucumber-ve)